# Restrict user to write review about the app at Apple app store

Tags: ios

Is it possible to restrict user from writing review for the app. In other word, can we disable / remove "Write a Review" option at Apple app store for the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, It is not provided by App Store.** User Reviews section is considered as integral part of App Store itself and no control is provided to developers to manipulate it other than see the statistics.

Although, it is not answered anywhere on Apple website. Only thing, i find relating is

> Customer ratings and reviews are also available in iTunes Connect for
>   you to view the most recent feedback from your users. Ratings or
>   reviews are available only for a version of an app that has or once
>   had the Ready for Sale status. tvOS binaries can only receive ratings,
>   so reviews are displayed only for iOS binaries

Answer (score 0):

In two words, no. It's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

They can set it but not by yourself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).